# fluentd and grok parser, add a key value

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, fluentd

I use an input syslog and the parser with grok expressions in fluentd.
It works well, but I would like to add a key in the fluentd parsed message.
The key would be the whole message itself. example with raw key:

```
{
time: grokked time
host: grokked hostname
...
raw : the whole raw message,
}
```

how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Add another filter:

```
 <filter **>
   @type record_transformer
   enable_ruby
   <record>
     raw ${record["message"]}
   </record>
 </filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

yep I got it working at the same time with

```
<filter syslog>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    raw ${record}
  </record>
</filter>
```